# Programmatically Uploading Android App to Google Play Store

Tags: google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to build a helper class to upload my Android app to the Google Play Store testing track as part of my CI/CD pipeline.  I did a bunch of Googling and found various examples, but none of them worked for me, and all of them were (apparently) using older versions of the `AndroidPublisher` API and calling deprecated methods.

So far, this is what I cobbled together.  I am obtaining the `GoogleCredentials` object successfully, but what I can't figure out is where should I insert the `accessToken` or `credentials` into the request code?

```
public void uploadToGooglePlay(String applicationName, String packageName, String credentialFilePath, String aabFilePath) throws Throwable {
    NetHttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();

    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
            new FileInputStream(credentialFilePath)
    );

    credentials.createScoped(
            AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER
    );

    AccessToken accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken();

    HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = httpTransport.createRequestFactory().getInitializer();

    AndroidPublisher.Builder androidPublisherBuilder = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
            httpTransport,
            jsonFactory,
            httpRequestInitializer
    );

    androidPublisherBuilder.setApplicationName(applicationName);

    AndroidPublisher androidPublisher = androidPublisherBuilder.build();

    AndroidPublisher.Edits.Insert insert = androidPublisher.edits().insert(
            packageName,
            null
    );

    AppEdit appEdit = insert.execute(); // THIS IS LINE 73 IN THE ERROR BELOW

    String editId = appEdit.getId();

    FileContent fileContent = new FileContent(
            "application/octet-stream",
            new File(aabFilePath)
    );

    AndroidPublisher.Edits.Bundles.Upload upload = androidPublisher.edits().bundles().upload(
            packageName,
            editId,
            fileContent
    );

    Bundle bundle = upload.execute();

    System.out.println("Version Code: " + bundle.getVersionCode());
    System.out.println("SHA Hash: " + bundle.getSha256());
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.whatever.app/edits
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:428)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at UploadToGooglePlay.uploadToGooglePlay(UploadToGooglePlay.java:73)
    at UploadToGooglePlay.main(UploadToGooglePlay.java:27)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple and obvious, but I have been pulling my hair out on this one for a while now.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The working code snippet is:

```
InputStream googlePlayServiceCredentials = new FileInputStream(
    credentialFilePath
);

GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
    .fromStream(googlePlayServiceCredentials)
    .createScoped(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER);

HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials);

AndroidPublisher.Builder androidPublisherBuilder = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
    httpTransport,
    jsonFactory,
    httpRequestInitializer
);
```

*However...*

The new Google OAuth 2 library does not support setting arbitraty connect/read timeouts on the HttpRequestInitializer, so this fails when uploading the AAB file (which takes forever).  So I use the code above now for operations that don't involve uploading an AAB, and I use the code below (which includes deprecated methods, but there's no way around this from what I can see):

```
InputStream googlePlayServiceCredentials = new FileInputStream(
    credentialFilePath
);

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(
    googlePlayServiceCredentials
).createScoped(
    Set.of(
        AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER
    )
);

HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
        credential.initialize(httpRequest);
        httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
        httpRequest.setReadTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
    }
};

AndroidPublisher.Builder androidPublisherBuilder = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
    httpTransport,
    jsonFactory,
    httpRequestInitializer
);
```